# Ajax file upload with paperclip

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, paperclip, ajax-upload

I'm using an ajax file upload script to upload a photo and using paperclip to process that photo in rails.

The script is
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

the script has a the variable name 'qqfile' hard-coded for the upload file-name, so the params that get passed are

```
qqfile=filename.jpg
```

in paperclip, my image object is called photo, so paperclip is expecting a photo element, and I '!!think!!' this is what is causing my problem.

I've tried the following

1) in my model I've tried aliasing the param name to the proper object name with

```
alias_attribute :qqfile, :photo
```

but when I do this, paperclip doesn't actually save the model at all.

I removed the alias_attribute and tried to provide an alias in my controller

```
    def create
    new_photo = {photo: params[:qqfile]}

    @temp_photo = TempPhoto.new(new_photo);
     if @temp_photo.save
        return render :text => '{success:true}'
     else
        return render :text => '{success:false}'
     end
    end
```

with this change, the model is saved to the db, but all the photo fields are NULL.

anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the remedy for this problem. It is a common solution. First of all download the [the js code](http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js) and save it as **jquey.form.js** in assets/javascripts. Include in application.js like

```
//= require jquery.form
```

Next is your view. Which may look like this

```
<div id="image_view">
  <%=image_tag @model.image_field.url %>
</div>
```

Next is Your form to upload image [You can use [bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) to render this form. Then it'll be more beautiful]

```
<%=form_for @model, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "form-id" }, :url => url_for(:controller => 'controller', :action => 'method_name') do | f | %>
 Upload picture : <%= f.file_field image_field %>
 <%= f.submit "Save changes", :id => :upload_pic %>
<% end %>
```

Then add some javascript to the file where the form is rendering

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#upload_pic').click(function() {
      $("#edit_form").ajaxForm({ target: "#image_view" }).submit();
      return false;
   });
 }); 
</script>
```

The controller method is just like a create or update method

```
#image_view is just a div. where the response from ajax function can be loaded.
```

Hope You people know how the model and Gemfile look like. I think It may help you. For any query please comment on the same thread. Thank you.